# How to process sequence of bytes in java?

Tags: java, string, char, arrays, bytebuffer

I have stream of bytes and I need to form these bytes as a frame when I get particular Header.
Example:

```
Header:    ABC  
Source:    DFDFDFDF'ABC'IEJENFAREABCOEKRERIERE
```

If ABC is detected, rest of the bytes `'IE'` in a string and `'JEN'` in a string and `'FARE'` in a String and again ABC is detected, hence `'OE'` in a string... likewise my byte stream has to be processed.

Is there any efficient way to process it ?

Answer (score 1):

If you have more than 1 header, I'd suggest using [Finite State Machines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine). However, if there is only one, simple pattern matching will suffice.

All you have to do is store characters starting from previously created frame. Whenever you read a character, update your state. If the end of a header is found, you've got your frame. If not, you can append the character to your incomplete frame.